# Parameterizing a SystemVerilog interface for optional array of a port element

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I would like to fill in the correct signal declarations and the modport declarations so that my interface and desire code example use case compiles in Vivado. I am working in SystemVerilog with .sv file extensions. The reason that I would like to "if statement" different signal declarations is so that the instantiating and using of my interface is way more elegant. I don't want the user to have to type many [0] to specify a single element in a single element array of 1st dimension with of 1 and 2nd dimension width of 1.

Bear with me on the purpose, I had to remove all elements of this code's application in my work. I have tailored it to be a very simple example.

I do not want someone to need to select the 0th and 0th element if the 1st dimension or the array is 1 and the second dimension of the array is 1.

For example I want the user to be able to do the following, but it doesn't compile. This is my base QUESTION. How do I achieve being able to have code as elegant as the following snippet?:

```
MyInterface # ( .DATA_WIDTH( 8 ), .ADDR_WIDTH( 8 ), .A1D( 1 ), .A2D( 1 ) ) my_signal () ;

assign my_signal.bus.data = 8'h20 ;
```

The error is:

```
[Synth 8-6038] cannot resolve hierarchical name for the item 'data' [".../File.sv":21]
```

Instead I find the user will have to do this for a specific signal that is 1 element total (there is no error with the following):

```
MyInterface # ( .DATA_WIDTH( 8 ), .ADDR_WIDTH( 8 ), .A1D( 1 ), .A2D( 1 ) ) my_signal () ;

assign my_signal.bus[0][0].data = 8'h20 ;
```

I felt that something like this should make this achievable with the following code:

```
interface MyInterface #(int DATA_W, ADDR_W, A1D, A2D) () ;

  typedef struct packed
    { logic                valid
    ; logic [ADDR_W-1:0]   addr
    ; logic [DATA_W-1:0]   data
    ; } SimpleStruct;

  if ( A1D == 1 ) begin
    SimpleStruct bus;
    logic ready;
  end
  else begin
    if ( A2D == 1 ) begin
      SimpleStruct [A1D-1:0] bus;
      logic        [A1D-1:0] ready;
    end
    else begin
      SimpleStruct [A1D-1:0][A2D-1:0] bus;
      logic        [A1D-1:0][A2D-1:0] ready;
    end
  end
  
  modport SNK (input  bus, output ready);
  modport SRC (output bus, input  ready);

endinterface
```

This didn't compile because bus and ready were "not declared" ... so I changed to a less elegant (i tried surrounding in generate just guessing, but that didn't help):

```
interface MyInterface #(int DATA_W, ADDR_W, A1D, A2D) () ;

  typedef struct packed
    { logic                valid
    ; logic [ADDR_W-1:0]   addr
    ; logic [DATA_W-1:0]   data
    ; } SimpleStruct;

  if ( A1D == 1 ) begin
    SimpleStruct bus;
    logic ready;

    modport SNK (input  bus, output ready);
    modport SRC (output bus, input  ready);
  end
  else begin
    if ( A2D == 1 ) begin
      SimpleStruct [A1D-1:0] bus;
      logic        [A1D-1:0] ready;
  
      modport SNK (input  bus, output ready);
      modport SRC (output bus, input  ready);
    end
    else begin
      SimpleStruct [A1D-1:0][A2D-1:0] bus;
      logic        [A1D-1:0][A2D-1:0] ready;
  
      modport SNK (input  bus, output ready);
      modport SRC (output bus, input  ready);
    end
  end

endinterface
```

The same desire goes for the case where the user wants to use a single dimensioned array where length > 1. For example:
imho desirable:

```
MyInterface # ( .DATA_WIDTH( 8 ), .ADDR_WIDTH( 8 ), .A1D( 3 ), .A2D( 1 ) ) my_signal () ;

assign my_signal.bus.data[0] = 8'h20 ;
assign my_signal.bus.data[1] = 8'h21 ;
assign my_signal.bus.data[2] = 8'h22 ;
```

I think the code above looks better than the code below. And the whole point of me experimenting or choosing to use interfaces is code reusability and elegance. I don't want the user to constantly be fighting with "I want a single element, but will get partially ambiguous error that is tough to figure out the solution to":
imho Not desirable:

```
MyInterface # ( .DATA_WIDTH( 8 ), .ADDR_WIDTH( 8 ), .A1D( 3 ), .A2D( 1 ) ) my_signal () ;

assign my_signal.bus.data[0][0] = 8'h20 ;
assign my_signal.bus.data[1][0] = 8'h21 ;
assign my_signal.bus.data[2][0] = 8'h22 ;
```

My desire is to have the user write the code they need to accomplish the complexity of elements that they want. There are most uses for a single element, some uses for a 1D array of elements, and few uses for 2D array of the elements. Since I will want to have one interface defined, I will have to allow for all the uses. I don't want in-elegant code needed just because I want the interface to support 2D and a user only needs a single element for their particular instantiation and code.

Comment: What you want to do is impossible in SV. Also bear in mind that every generate block (and your 'if' statement is the generate block) adds a hierarchical path to the name of the 'bus' variable which in your case would become something like `my_signal.genblk1.bus.data`. Where 'genblk' is automatically generated (since you have not provided a name to the 'begin') and it will be different in every `begin...end` pair in the generate block.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I totally agree about the gen statement baggage. I will not use a generate statement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to do something like you describe is to use a type parameter and to define types outside of the interface. Here is an example.

```
interface MyInterface #(type SimpleStruct = logic) () ;  
  SimpleStruct  bus;
  logic         ready;
   
  modport SNK (input  bus, output ready);
  modport SRC (output bus, input  ready);

endinterface

module mymod #(int DATA_W = 1, int ADDR_W = 1) ();

  typedef struct packed
    { logic                valid
    ; logic [ADDR_W-1:0]   addr
    ; logic [DATA_W-1:0]   data
    ; } SimpleStruct;
  
  MyInterface #(SimpleStruct) if1();
  
  typedef SimpleStruct[2] SimpleStruct2;
  MyInterface #(SimpleStruct2) if2();

  typedef SimpleStruct[2][2] SimpleStruct3;
  MyInterface #(SimpleStruct3) if3();

endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but in my honest opinion the code that you shared is less elegant than the original solution in the question. I do not want to pass parameters to size vectors into the parameter list for a module anymore, I want that to always be properly inferable at compile time because I am using an "interface". With that said, I think that the idea of using a typedef to basically extend the interface multiple times (up to 3 times) to setup a single element version, a 1D version and a 2D version may be useful. I would have to confirm in my testing. Without intro'ing param'd mod